# dbicdump and set_on_create with TimeStamp

Tags: perl, dbix-class

In my webapp all of the tables have a *created_date* field. I'm using [DBIx::Class::TimeStamp](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-TimeStamp-0.14/lib/DBIx/Class/TimeStamp.pm) so that I can use `set_on_create` and `set_on_update`  while declaring the columns.

Im using `dbicdump` to auto-generate the schema classes. Can `dbicdump` add the `set_on_create` etc while generating the schema ?